# 2nd build to PDF stops with 3 errors when previous PDF is still open - Texniccenter 2.02, MikTex,

Tags: pdf, texniccenter

IT reimaged my PC (Windows 7) and I had to reinstall all the software they don't have on their standard image - including MikTeX and TeXniccenter.

If I try to compile and output a PDF the second time, but I left the last PDF open after viewing it, the compile stops.  See below for information from log file, the LaTeX and Viewer profiles.

I remember having this problem before, and a colleague gave me a solution (other than remembering to close the PDF every time I want to recompile) and that was to change the build profile in some way so that it closed the PDF before the build, but I can't remember where the change needs to be made or what the code is (and the colleague has left).

Thanks for any help.

From log file:

! I can't write on file `"0 - 10-4 polar curves.pdf"'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
 
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
l.35 \myclass

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

[image: Latex Profile]
[image: Viewer Profile]

Comment: Do not use blanks or special characters like ä in your filenames ...